# How to import from Microsoft TFS server using the Eclipse IDE on Mac OS X

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-plugin, teamprise

I'm unable to connect to a Microsoft Team Foundation Server from my Mac using Eclipse and the Eclipse plugin. [Here's what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQDyC.png).

Answer (score 0):

sometimes the download/extract of Team Explorer Everywhere seems to go wrong.  I don't fully know why but I've seen a handful of reports of issues like this.  They are nearly always resolved by doing a fresh download and install of the TFS plug-in.  If you are downloading again then it's probably worth going for the [TEE 2010 SP1 Beta](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=4449babd-1dc8-40e3-9e27-2b743a4a173c&displaylang=en).  Otherwise you will need to uninstall the plug-in from Eclipse and then install again.